# Trouble with curl in php

Tags: php, rest, http, curl, get

So on my webserver, I am making a rest api that works perfectly when you visit the page and set get parameters in the URL. I am now trying to add a page where the php access the api and gets the value that it returns, like with the Wikipedia api. I have tested using curl and file_get_contents with multiple sites, and they both worked fine with low loading times. I have also accessed my api successfully from runscope, and it works fine. So why is it that when I try to read my file on my server from the same server, it just loads forever and times out? I have been looking all over for hours and I can't find anyone with this same issue. Should I just host my api elsewhere?

Comment: It'd be best if you show an example script of what you're doing - to debug

Comment: @Darren I have tried a ton of different ways to do this, and everything works except for anything on my server. I can post code tomorrow when I have access to my computer. (On mobile ATM)

Comment: Any code that you have tried so far??

Comment: @Saurabh Extremely sorry, but I am on mobile right now. I will post code tomorrow morning. Probably should have asked this tomorrow... Sorry!

Comment: @lucadem1313 Sure thing..:)

Comment: @Saurabh I got it working, had to make a subdomain that referred to my api, never worked with same domain as file accessing